# 100% height column with fixed sidebar

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck trying to get this to work. It looks right when the content of the main column fills the page height but not when it doesn't.

Looks right: http://jsfiddle.net/creativetags/ngv4H/1/

Doesn't look right: http://jsfiddle.net/creativetags/EAuBc/1/

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='container-wrap'>
        <nav class='tabnav'>Some nav menu items here</nav>
        <div class='container-inner'>
            <div class='clearfix' id='mainwrap'>
                <div class='columns' id='main'>
                     <h2>Main content scrolls here</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='columns' id='side'>
                <div class="sidecontent">
                    <p>Fixed Side panel</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using a faux sidebar column that is fixed, so when you scroll the main column it stays in view.

I need the background of `.container-inner` to fill to the bottom of the page, even when the content doesn't reach the bottom.

`.tabnav` needs to show the background image from the body tag, so `.container-inner` can't start from the top of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated demos with [large content](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/ngv4H/3/) and [small content](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/EAuBc/3/), using the same CSS.

**Summary of the changes**

*Fixing the main content*

- Apply the white bg color to both `.container-wrap` and `.container-inner`.
- Set `.container` and `.container-wrap` to `height:100%;`.
- The background image underneath `.tabnav` is now covered by a white bg color, so re-apply the bg image to `.tabnav`. **This is the key part of the solution**.

*Updating the sidebar*

- Set `#side` and `.sidecontent` to `height:100%;`.
- Move the side bg image from `.container` to `.sidecontent`.

**CSS added**

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    ...
}
.container-wrap {
    width: 660px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
.tabnav {
    background: #1d1d1b url("http://cat.storehousebelfast.com/assets/bg.jpg") repeat fixed top left;
}
#side {
    height: 100%;
    ...
}
.sidecontent {
    background: transparent url("http://cat.storehousebelfast.com/assets/right-column.gif") repeat-y top right;
    height: 100%;
    ...
}
```

**CSS removed**

```
.container {
    background: transparent url("http://cat.storehousebelfast.com/assets/right-column.gif") repeat-y top right;   /* Remove this */
    ...
}
.container-inner {
    min-height: 100%;   /* Remove this */
    height: 100%;       /* Remove this */
    ...
}
```